# Get Local Browser Time on my application java

Tags: java, datetime, grails

My application server runs on the eastern timeZone server. so when I do new Date() I always get Eastern time for now. How do I get time based on client's local/browser time?

Comment: what are you doing with the time? If you are storing it on the server, you'd be better off storing that in UTC or GMT

Answer (score 0):

Q: What means do you have to communicate with the client?

A few suggestions:

1) The client browser's time zone might be among the HTTP headers

2) If your client was running a Java applet, "new java.util.Calendar" could give you the client's time and timezone.

3) If your server were prepared to accept an Ajax call, you could use Javascript.  For example:

- http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JavaScript's timezoneOffset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If server is aware of users's timezone

```
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone zone);
```

Otherwise you could send the date value including timezone from client to server, say in 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss Z' format.